# C# IO Reading and Writing file in use error

Tags: c#, file-io

I have a library that handles reading and writing a cache file. This library is used by a Windows Service and several instances of a console application on the same machine. The console application runs when a user logs in.

I am getting occasional IO errors saying the cache file is in use by another process. I assume that collisions are occurring between the different application instances and service trying to read and write at the same time.

Is there a way to lock the file when it is in use and force all other requests to "wait in line" to access the file?

```
    private void SaveCacheToDisk(WindowsUser user) {
        string serializedCache = SerializeCache(_cache);
        //encryt
        serializedCache = AES.Encrypt(serializedCache);

        string path = user == null ? ApplicationHelper.CacheDiskPath() :
            _registry.GetCachePath(user);
        string appdata = user == null ? ApplicationHelper.ClientApplicationDataFolder() :
            _registry.GetApplicationDataPath(user);

        if (Directory.Exists(appdata) == false) {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(appdata);
        }

        if (File.Exists(path) == false) {
            using (FileStream stream = File.Create(path)) { }
        }

        using (FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Truncate)) {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream)) {
                writer.Write(serializedCache);
            }
        }
    }

    private string ReadCacheFromDisk(WindowsUser user) {
        //cache file path
        string path = user == null ? ApplicationHelper.CacheDiskPath() :
            _registry.GetCachePath(user);

        using (FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open)) {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
                string serializedCache = reader.ReadToEnd();
                //decrypt
                serializedCache = AES.Decrypt(serializedCache);

                return serializedCache;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you could use a [mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) and permit access only when holding the mutex.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cross-process [EventWaitHandle](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_CrossProcessEventWaitHandle). This lets you create and use a WaitHandle that's identified across processes by name. A thread is notified when it's its turn, does some work, and then indicates it's done allowing another thread to proceed.

Note that this only works if every process/thread is referring to the same named WaitHandle.

The [EventWaitHandle constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.eventwaithandle.aspx) with strings in their signature create named system synchronization events.

Answer (score 1):

One option you could consider is having the console applications route their file access *through* the service, that way there's only one process accessing the file and you can synchronise access to it there.

One way of implementing this is by [remoting across an IPC channel](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_syntax/remoting/article.php/c9251) (and here's [another example](http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2005/01/04/346180.aspx) from weblogs.asp.net). We used this technique in a project for the company I work for and it works well, with our specific case providing a way for a .net WebService to talk to a Windows Service running on the same machine.

**Sample based on the weblogs.asp.net example**

Basically what you need to do with the code below is create a Solution, add two Console Apps (one called "Server" and the other called "Client" and one Library to it. Add a reference to the Library to *both* console apps, paste the code below in and add a reference to System.Runtime.Remoting to both Server & Console.

Run the Server app, then run the client app. Observe the fact that the server app has a message passed to it by the client. You can extend this to any number of messages/tasks

```
// Server:
using System;
using System.Runtime.Remoting;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Ipc;
namespace RemotingSample
{
    public class Server
    {
        public Server()
        { 
        }
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            IpcChannel chan = new IpcChannel("Server");
            //register channel
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chan, false);
            //register remote object
            RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(
                        typeof(RemotingSample.RemoteObject),
                   "RemotingServer",
                   WellKnownObjectMode.SingleCall);

            Console.WriteLine("Server Activated");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

// Client:
using System;
using System.Runtime.Remoting;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Ipc;
using RemotingSample;
namespace RemotingSample
{
    public class Client
    {
        public Client()
        { 
        }
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            IpcChannel chan = new IpcChannel("Client");
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chan);
            RemoteObject remObject = (RemoteObject)Activator.GetObject(
                        typeof(RemotingSample.RemoteObject),
                        "ipc://Server/RemotingServer");
            if (remObject == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("cannot locate server");
            }
            else
            {
                remObject.ReplyMessage("You there?");
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

// Shared Library:
using System;
using System.Runtime.Remoting;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;

namespace RemotingSample
{
    public class RemoteObject : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public RemoteObject()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Remote object activated");
        }
        public String ReplyMessage(String msg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client : " + msg);//print given message on console
            return "Server : I'm alive !";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rob this sounds interesting could you please explain a bit more or provide some psuedo code? Sorry I've never done anything like that before.

Comment: @modernzombie - The best I can suggest is that you follow the example on one of the two referenced pages, I'll have a go at putting together a simpler sample, so watch this space :)

Comment: @Rob thank you. I didn't see those 2 examples when I posted the comment.

Comment: Annoyingly the sample from weblogs.asp.net didn't work straight off. I'm going to drop a code sample into the answer that I've compiled and run (based on it) that works for me =)

Comment: @Rob awesome. I really appreciate this! I'm trying it out now.

Comment: @modernzombie, no worries - glad to help :) It is a bit heavy going to start with, but you'll probably get going pretty quickly once you've got your head round the base implementation above :)

Comment: @Rob I really like this approach. I wish I had this when I was starting out with the project. Unfortunately to do this would require a reworking of the project's architecture which I spent several weeks working on.

Comment: @modernzombie, there's always v2 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `TextWriter.Synchronized` method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.synchronized.aspx

This should let you do this:

```
TextWriter.Synchronized(writer).Write(serializedCache);
```

Comment: +1: This looks like it does exactly what the OP needs.  In fact, the MSDN on the `StreamWriter` class explicitly suggests replacing `StreamWriter` with `TextWriter.Synchronized` if thread-safe output is needed.

Comment: Synchronized is a static method.

Comment: I believe this will only work for *in-process* synchronization.  The question is actually about *inter-process* synchronization, and only a Mutex has OS-level scope.

Comment: This did not work. I applied it to every StreamReader and StreamWriter. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Aaronaught: Oh yeah, you're right.  I wasn't paying careful enough attention to what the OP wanted.